# Problem executing with Python+MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am not getting the reason why my python script is not working though I hv put all the things correctly as my knowledge.The below test I did and it worked fine.But when I import the MySQLdb in my script it gives error as no module name MySQLdb.

**C:\Python26>python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67517, Dec  4 2008, 16:51:00) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       **

Kindly let me know the reason for this error.

And all the development is going on in windows XP, python 2.6, mysql 4.0.3

Earlier 1 hour back I have posted the question but some mistake was there in the question itself..

Answer (score 0):

seems like the path is not set properly.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html the link explains setting path on windows. also try this on idle to check if path is set
import sys
sys.path

Comment: Also check if you have installed the correct version of "MySQL for Python" just saw you are using python 2.6.1 and the default installer for "MySql for python" doesnt support 2.6 (yet)